# drawing predict line on an R graph

Tags: r

I have a time series data:

output of x data frame:

```
Date  vol
1990  12
1991  13
1992  15
1994  18
1995  20
1996  35
```

I am trying to plot this data and predict 4 year ahead as below:

```
plot(x$Date, x$vol, col="blue")
x.lm<-lm(x$Vol ~ x$Date)
x.pre<-predict(x.lm, n.ahead=4)
abline(x.pre, col="red")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  invalid a=, b= specification
```

can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you read `?abline` carefully and compare that with `?lines` and think about whether your call to `abline` makes any sense whatsoever, given the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You capitalized "Vol" in `x.lm<-lm(x$Vol ~ x$Date)`.

Try

```
x.lm<-lm(x$vol ~ x$Date)
```

Also, you're not going to be able to pass the value of `predict()` into `abline` like that without some extra modification. Since you're not doing any sophisticated prediction, but really just wanting to plot the linear fit, you could plot the line using

```
abline(x.lm, col="red")
```

If you separate your variables and then use the newdata parameter in `predict`, you should be able to get the actual predictions. That would probably be the cleanest way to do it. For instance:

```
y <- x$vol
x <- x$Date
x.lm <- lm(y~x)
predict(x.lm, data.frame(x=1997:2000))
```

This will return the predictions for 1997 - 2000. I believe the "x" in `data.frame(x=1997:2000)` must match the variable you put into `lm()` as your x variable. In your case, that has a dollar sign accessor, which makes the whole thing a bit more complex. I'd just take the approach above and rename the x component fed into your `lm()` function as a valid variable name which can be referenced later.

Comment: I corrected that still having problems. abline(x.pre, col="red") command is not working

Comment: yes, I can do abline(x.lm, col="red"), but I would like to be able to predict ahead. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Updated to handle the specific predictions.

Comment: I still get this error: Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  invalid a=, b= specification

Comment: Did you assign the output to x.pre?   x.pre <- predict(x.lm, data.frame(x=1997:2000))

Comment: yes, first I plotted the original data frame, then I did lines(x, x.pre), I dont see any lines

Comment: Also, you're not going to be able to use `abline` to plot points. You can use the `points` function, potentially. Something like `points(1997:2000, x.pre)`

Comment: still not able to draw the line, I can print the values.

Comment: I think you'll need to spend some time reading the documentation for `predict.lm` and `abline`. These functions are able to do what you're looking for, you just need to find the right combination to plot them out however it is you want to plot them.

Comment: I can do plot to create the original data. After doing that, I would like to add the predicted values to the same graph. I can do separate graphs for orinal data and predicted values. When I try to add the predicted values to the original graphs, it does not show. Any way, thanks

Comment: Add `xlim=c(1990,2000), ylim=c(12, 50)` to change the limits of the axes.